# How can I save documents to Lotus Quickr using C# .Net?

Tags: c#, attachment, lotus-notes

Where is documentation describing how to save to Quickr using C# .Net? I'm converting a Lotus Notes application to WPF. The old Notes app contains several attached documents (Word, Excel, pdfs etc). My company recently started using Quickr as a document repository. My first challenge will be figuring out how to retrieve existing doc attachments for the conversion, but this can be done manually if necessary. The bigger issue is I need a way to allow users to save attachments using my new WPF app. I found a web service that retrieves docs from Quickr but it's useless because it doesn't save. I'm aware that there is a REST ATOM API but I have not found any useful documentation or samples written in C#.

**Any suggestions on how to save documents Quickr from C# .Net?**

Answer (score 1):

Lotus® Quickr application programming interfaces (APIs) enable you to integrate your Lotus® Quickr content with other applications. APIs are available for the following content services Places, Templates, Policy, Search, and Documents. Using these interfaces, you can programmatically access and update much of the same information that you can access and update through the Lotus® Quickr user interface.
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lqwiki.nsf/xpViewCategories.xsp?lookupName=API%20Documentation